# Erro em syntaxe golang GET com parâmetros opcionais

Tags: golang

Estou tentando filtrar meus registros com base em um parâmetro "Name"

Eu fiz essa handler function:

```
func GetFuncionaries(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var f model.Funcionary
    var t util.App
    var d db.DB
    err := d.Connection()
    db := d.DB
    defer db.Close()

    Id, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.FormValue("Id"))
    Name:= r.FormValue("Name")

    f.Id = int64(Id)
    f.Name = Name

    funcionaries, err := f.GetFuncionaries(db)
    if err != nil {
            log.Printf("[handler/GetFuncionaries-  Error: %s", err.Error())
            t.ResponseWithError(w, http.StatusInternalServerError, err.Error(), "")
        }
        return
    }
    t.ResponseWithJSON(w, http.StatusOK, funcionaries, 0, 0)
}
```

E essa é minha função model:

```
func (f *Funcionary) GetFuncionaries(db *sql.DB) ([]Funcionary, error) {
    var values []interface{}
    var where []string

    if f.Name != "" {
        where = append(where, "Name= ?")
        values = append(values, f.Name)
    }


    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT Id, Data, Role, Name
                    FROM funcionaries
                    WHERE 1=1 `+strings.Join(where, " AND "), values...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    funcionaries:= []Funcionary{}
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        var funcionary Funcionary
        if err = rows.Scan(&funcionario.Id, &funcionario.Name, &Others...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        funcionaries = append(funcionaries, funcionary)
    }
    return funcionaries, nil
}
```

Porém quando eu faço uma requisição no postman:

http://localhost:8000/api/funcionaries?Name=a

Eu recebo:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Name= ?' at line 3",

Estou esquecendo de algo?

Comment: Você já rodou a query "na mão" e está funcional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é uma das falhas no design do pacote database/sql, pois o mesmo deixa a cargo dos drivers a implementação das *bind variables*, o que não permite ser genérico. O que você precisa lembrar é que cada driver pode mudar esse símbolo, hoje o que conheço é que para mysql se usa ?, para postgresql se usa $1, oracle não lembro, mas parece que é igual ao postgresql. Veja o manual/documentação do driver do banco que você está utilizando.

Segue uma discussão sobre isso: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/p-QPMneatDI

No final da discussão uma pessoa dá uma sugestão capaz de contornar esse problema, apesar de não ser uma coisa bonita de se ver, resolve, hehehe.

:)